# Photo location available through API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, location, photo

Is there a way of accessing a photos location through the graph API ? I dont see it documented

In facebook I can add a location tag to a photo when uploading, but I dont seem to be able to retrieve this later programmatically

I know its possible to get the location of an album.

hope you can help

thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, photo location is not currently exposed thru the API.  You can check to see if someone has already filed a request for it at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs and if not, then file a bug.  Either way, could you please post the bug # here for other stack overflow users who stumble across this question.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The place is field in now available through the API when fetching photos.